# Error PayPal thrown but it wasn't a PayPal payment

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal

I have this error when I'm trying to pay an order:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: 
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express::isOrderAuthorizationAllowed() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment, null given, 
called in /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php on line 41 and 
defined in /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Adminhtml/Express.php:169 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php(41): Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express->isOrderAuthorizationAllowed(NULL) 
#1 /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Paypal\Plugin\OrderCanInvoice->afterCanInvoice(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), false) 
#2 /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() 
#3 /var/www/axiane-portailclient/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Orde in /var/www/axiane-portailclient/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Adminhtml/Express.php on line 169
```

I don't know why, because it's not a paypal step.

I'm on magento 2.2.5

Error is showing after **save($order)**

```
public function updateOrderStatus(){
    $increment_id = $this->loadOrderIncrementId();
    $order = $this->_order->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
    $order->setState(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The called method from the paypal module is in a plugin called after the method `canInvoice()` of the order model and is therefore called for each order independent of the payment of the order.

So the question in your case is: Why doesn't have the order you are trying to save a payment? Because `$order->getPayment()` is `null`, that's what the error message says.

It might be that you don't find an order to the given `$increment_id`. I would suggest to check if the order exists and change the code to something like this:

```
if ($order->getId()){
   $order->setState(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
   $order->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
   $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
}
```

If your order exists, but has no payment than you might have some inconsistent data for that order.

Comment: Yes that was just that... $order was null because is ID was null... Thanks. But it doesn't explained why this trigger a Paypal error ^^