# After Payment not redirecting to success page and getting this error with magento2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4

[19-Mar-2020 09:30:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express::isOrderAuthorizationAllowed() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment, null given, called in /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php on line 41 and defined in /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Adminhtml/Express.php:169
Stack trace:

## 0 /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php(41): Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express->isOrderAuthorizationAllowed(NULL)

## 1 /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Paypal\Plugin\OrderCanInvoice->afterCanInvoice(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), false)

## 2 /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()

## 3 /home/hofadmin/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Interceptor.php( in /home/hofadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Adminhtml/Express.php on line 169

Comment: Delete the `generated` folder and try again.

Comment: Thank For the reply, but some times its redirecting to the success page and sometimes it throwing the same error

Comment: hello, i have tried but still same error kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well Please check below link this might help you.The reason behind this issue is to call payment function on before checking invoice:

[Error PayPal thrown](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266646/error-paypal-thrown-but-it-wasnt-a-paypal-payment)

Hopet this helps.

Comment: I have GOne through this but don't know in which file i have to change and how,  kindly do needful

Comment: You need to debug this while magento is creating order their you need to check.There must be some function where you are not providing appropriate data to a function.

Comment: Deleted Generated Dolder from root and run this Following commands,
And which is successfully generated no bug found
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Kindly Help , i am Stuck, kindly share file path so i can edit this

Comment: @ShubhamKhandelwal Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325882/57334